# Javascript, flask, making sure at least one checkbox from each "type" is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I have a flask template that loads a form in a modal window for me. The form has 3 drop downs which work well with the required attribute, but it also has two "sets" of checkboxes. Within each set the user must pick one. I am new to javascript and can't seem to get anything to work. The days and actions have to have separate ids in order for the css to work properly with the special checkboxes we have. How can my users be forced to select one action and one day?

***EDIT***
Yes, the goal is for someone to be able to check multiple days, or both values for the two actions. I am pretty terrible with css, so if someone has a way to accomplish this with multiple classes then I can certainly make edits.

```
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function checkCheckBoxes(theForm) {
    if (
    theForm.m.checked == false &&
    theForm.t.checked == false &&
    theForm.w.checked == false &&
    theForm.th.checked == false &&
    theForm.f.checked == false &&
    theForm.s.checked == false &&
    theForm.sn.checked == false &&) 
    {
        alert ('You didn\'t choose a day!');
        return false;
    } else {    
        return true;
    }
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box" title="Schedule">
   <div class="wrapper">
    <a data-popup="On demand" href="#refresh" value="Refresh Now">Refresh Now</a>
   </div>
    <a href="#schedule" value="Change Schedule">Change Schedule</a>
</div>

<aside class="modal" id="schedule">
<h2 >Refresh Schedule</h2>
     <section >
         <div class="onoffswitch">
             <form name="onoff" method="post" action="{{ url_for('togglebool') }}">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="onoffswitch" onchange="this.form.submit()" {{ checkval }}>
                 <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="onoffswitch">
                    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                 </label>
             </form>
         </div>
<p id="schedule-mssg"><strong>When should this occur?</strong></p>

    <form method='POST' name="schedule_time" action="{{ url_for('info') }}" onsubmit="return checkCheckBoxes(this);">
        <select class="custom-dropdown" name="hour" id="hour" required>
            <option value="" selected disabled>Hour</option>
            {% for i in hours %}
            <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <select class="custom-dropdown" name="minute" id="minute" required>
            <option value="" selected disabled>Minute</option>
            {% for i in minutes %}
            <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <select class="custom-dropdown" name="period" id="period" required>
            <option value="" selected disabled>AM/PM</option>
            <option>AM</option>
            <option>PM</option>
            </select>


<!--Actions, at least one must be checked-->
            <input type="checkbox" name="action" id="code" class="css-checkbox" value="code" checked><label for="code" class="css-label">Code</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="action" id="database" class="css-checkbox" value="database" checked><label for="database" class="css-label">Database</label>
            <div id="schedule-form">


> <!--Days, at least one must be checked in addition to at least one action-->

            <input type="checkbox" name="m" id="m" class="css-checkbox" value="1" checked><label for="m" class="css-label">Mon</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="t" id="t" class="css-checkbox" value="2" checked><label for="t" class="css-label">Tues</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="w" id="w" class="css-checkbox" value="3" checked><label for="w" class="css-label">Wed</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="th" id="th" class="css-checkbox" value="4" checked><label for="th" class="css-label">Thur</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="f" id="f" class="css-checkbox" value="5" checked><label for="f" class="css-label">Fri</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="s" id="s" class="css-checkbox" value="6" checked><label for="s" class="css-label">Sat</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="sn" id="sn" class="css-checkbox" value="7" checked><label for="sn" class="css-label">Sun</label>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="sched-sub" id="schedule-sub" value="Save Changes"; />
             <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
        </form>

            </section>    
        <footer class="cf">
        </footer>
    </section>  
        </aside>
        </body>
```

**CSS for checkboxes**

```
/* Begin Checkboxes */
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:-1000; 
    left:-1000px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
    height:1px; 
    width:1px; 
    margin:-1px; 
    padding:0; 
    border:0;
}
input[type="checkbox"].css-checkbox + label.css-label {         padding-left: 27px;
    height: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 22px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    font-size: 120%;
    margin: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
background-position: 0 -22px;
}

label.css-label {
    background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_cc5c7a8c1727e75f2de9c422739d0ad5.png);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
            }

/* End Checkboxes */
```

Comment: so you want something to check that the client has checked at least one checkbox? If so is it possible for you to add another class name to your input elements?

Comment: Not too sure, I adapted the css from someone else. I am not great with css, can a second class be added and be used to differentiate the two "sets".

Comment: If you add another class name to your elements it will not cause problems with css. Elements can have multiple class names as you use them to identify different groups of elements. My answer below has 2 class names. Have a look and see if the javascript helps. If it doesn't just leave a comment explaining why it isn't working for you or display the errors so I can try understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't replied to my question I will assume you're allowing the client to select multiple days, hence using checkboxes.

> This will require you to add the class name `Days` to your checkbox elements.

```js
function CheckBoxes(){
//Get all input type="checkbox elements"
var days = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");    
var Selected=0;
//Loop through checkbox elements
for(var i=0; i<days.length; i++){
// Does this element have "Days" in the class name and is it checked?
     if(days[i].className.indexOf('Days')>-1 && days[i].checked){
     // Yes/True - Add 1 to the Selected Variable
     Selected++;
     }
}
//Is Selected more than 0?
if(Selected>0){
// One or more checkboxes are checked.
alert("Selection Found!");
}else{ 
// No checked checkboxes
alert("No Selection Found!");
//Stop the form from being submitted
event.preventDefault();
}
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit="CheckBoxes();">
     <input type="checkbox" class="Days css-checkbox" value="1"/>
     <input type="checkbox" class="Days css-checkbox" value="2"/>
     <input type="checkbox" class="Days css-checkbox" value="3"/>
     <input type="checkbox" class="Days css-checkbox" value="4"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

I have put comments in the source code but if you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

If you want to stop the form from submitting you can use `event.preventDefault();`

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: What about making sure they also checked one of the "action" checkboxes. I added some comments to my original post and some comments to the html. Both kinds of check boxes need to reside in the same form.

Comment: @MinelrG Sorry, I have just noticed your edit on the comment. If you should be able to edit the function to add in a check for `action` this is where you need to understand the answer so you know how to expend/edit. Please time some time to read the answer, if you don't understand anything I will be more than happy to explain it. Once you understand it, you shouldn't have any problems expanding on it to check for `action` checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Thanks again to NewToJS.

```
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function CheckBoxes(){
//Get all input type="checkbox elements"
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");    
var total_Days=0;
var total_Actions=0;
//Loop through checkbox elements
for(var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++){
// Does this element have "Days" in the class name and is it checked?
     if(boxes[i].className.indexOf('Days')>-1 && boxes[i].checked){
     // Yes/True - Add 1 to the Total_Days Variable
     total_Days++;
     }

     if(boxes[i].className.indexOf('Actions')>-1 && boxes[i].checked){
     // Yes/True - Add 1 to the Selected Variable
     total_Actions++;
     }
}
//Is Selected more than 0?
if(total_Days>0 && total_Actions>0) {
// One or more checkboxes are checked.
}else{ 
// No checked checkboxes
alert("You must select an action, and at least one day.");
}
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box" title="Schedule">
   <div class="wrapper">
    <a data-popup="On demand" href="#refresh" value="Refresh Now">Refresh Now</a>
   </div>
    <a href="#schedule" value="Change Schedule">Change Schedule</a>
</div>

<aside class="modal" id="schedule">
<h2 >Refresh Schedule</h2>
     <section >
         <div class="onoffswitch">
             <form name="onoff" method="post" action="{{ url_for('togglecron') }}">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="onoffswitch" onchange="this.form.submit()" {{ checkval }}>
                 <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="onoffswitch">
                    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                 </label>
             </form>
         </div>
<p id="schedule-mssg"><strong>When should this site refresh?</strong></p>

    <form method='POST' name="schedule_time" action="{{ url_for('info') }}" onsubmit="CheckBoxes()">
        <select class="custom-dropdown" name="hour" id="hour" required>
            <option value="" selected disabled>Hour</option>
            {% for i in hours %}
            <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <select class="custom-dropdown" name="minute" id="minute" required>
            <option value="" selected disabled>Minute</option>
            {% for i in minutes %}
            <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <select class="custom-dropdown" name="period" id="period" required>
            <option value="" selected disabled>AM/PM</option>
            <option>AM</option>
            <option>PM</option>
        </select>
        <input type="checkbox" name="action" id="code" class="Actions css-checkbox" value="code" checked><label for="code" class="css-label">Code</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="action" id="database" class="Actions css-checkbox" value="database" checked><label for="database" class="css-label">Database</label>
        <div id="schedule-form">
        <input type="checkbox" name="m" id="m" class="Days css-checkbox" value="1" checked><label for="m" class="css-label">Mon</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="t" id="t" class="Days css-checkbox" value="2" checked><label for="t" class="css-label">Tues</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="w" id="w" class="Days css-checkbox" value="3" checked><label for="w" class="css-label">Wed</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="th" id="th" class="Days css-checkbox" value="4" checked><label for="th" class="css-label">Thur</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="f" id="f" class="Days css-checkbox" value="5" checked><label for="f" class="css-label">Fri</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="s" id="s" class="Days css-checkbox" value="6" checked><label for="s" class="css-label">Sat</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sn" id="sn" class="Days css-checkbox" value="7" checked><label for="sn" class="css-label">Sun</label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="sched-sub" id="schedule-sub" value="Save Changes"; />
         <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    </form>

        </section>    
    <footer class="cf">
    </footer>
</section>  
    </aside>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    function checkSelectedAtleastOne(clsName) {
         if (selectedValue == "select") return false;

         var i = 0;
         $("." + clsName).each(function () {

             if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                 i = 1;
             }

         });

         if (i == 0) {
                alert("Please select atleast one users");
                return false;
         } else if (i == 1) {
                return true;
         }


         return true;

     }


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#chkSearchAll').click(function () {

             var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
             $('.clsChkSearch').each(function () {
                 var checkBox = $(this);
                 if (checked) {
                     checkBox.prop('checked', true);
                 }
                 else {
                     checkBox.prop('checked', false);
                 }
             });

         });


            //for select and deselect 'select all' check box when clicking individual check boxes
         $(".clsChkSearch").click(function () {

             var i = 0;
             $(".clsChkSearch").each(function () {

                 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

                 } else {

                     i = 1;//unchecked
                 }

             });

             if (i == 0) {
                 $("#chkSearchAll").attr("checked", true)
             } else if (i==1){

                 $("#chkSearchAll").attr("checked", false)
             }

         });


});



</script>
   <!-- TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "exact",
        elements: "txtDesc"

    });
</script>
<!-- /TinyMCE -->


<style type="text/css">

    .clsChksearch
    {
       margin:0px;  

    }
 </style>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.